# How to Integrate the Sjeng Chess Engine into a SwuiftUI Project?

Tags: c, swift, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am trying to make a simple IOS chess app in SwiftUI.  I want to use the Sjeng chess engine the same way that the Apple (MacOS) chess game does.

I am assuming the following:

- the Sjeng engine is a static library in C.
- it should be possible to integrate/interface with this library from basically any platform/language/architecture -- in my case, I would need to create a bridge to the C code using an objective-c wrapper and expose that to the Swift code.

I have successfully opened the Apple chess game source code in Xcode.

*How do I "graft" the sjeng component from the Apple app into a newly created blank/default SwiftUI project such that it will successfully build (and actually does build the sjeng component)?  I think I can figure out the rest after that point.*

What I have tried:

- simply dragging it over. (don't know what I was thinking)
- adding [all the same sources that the sjeng target uses in its own sources and headers in the apple app] to my main target (results in build errors (duplicate symbols) no doubt because I have no idea what build settings to use)
- creating a separate sjeng target in my app and attempting to duplicate all config from the apple app sjeng target.  (can't figure out how to create a target of the same type as the one in the apple app -- the available settings/options are different no matter what I do it seems)